# GROUP BY a condition in MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, group-by

I'm creating an Inventory System using MySQLi. I have a table called PRODUCTS and I have two columns (stock,security_level) that I want to get some data by Grouping results according to a condition. Here's some pseudo code of what I need to achieve.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'products' Where 'status' = 1 GROUP BY (if 'security_level' - 'stock' <=0 and if 'security_level' - 'stock' > 0)...
```

So I can get a group of product under the security level and another group over the security level with just one query.

How can I do this query?

Comment: So you just want to get a count of how many products are over the security level and how many are under?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT stock,COUNT(security_level) AS S FROM 'products' Where 'status' = 1 GROUP BY stock;
```

This will count all security levels grouped by stock. To get a group of product under the security level and another group over the security level, you can sort it in server side language while fetching results.

PHP example,

```
    $sql = "SELECT stock,COUNT(security_level) as S FROM 'products' Where 'status'=1 GROUP BY stock";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           if($row["S"] <= 0){
           echo $row["stock"]." under 0" ;
           }
           if($row["S"] > 0){
           echo $row["stock"]." greater than 0";
           }
         }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a count of how many products are over the security level and how many are under, you need to create a variable which represents that state and group by that variable. For example

```
SELECT CASE WHEN security_level <= stock THEN 'Ok'
            ELSE 'Low Stock'
            END AS stock_status,
       COUNT(*)
FROM products
GROUP BY stock_status
```